# Is it alright to place equality constraints on the items loadings for assessing configural invariance using effect coding approach?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, mplus, invariance

I am wondering if somebody can help me out with the syntax to run a longitudinal invariance test using effects coding approach in Mplus.

I have figured out that to run a CFA with effects coding, I would label all the factor loadings and then add MODEL CONSTRAINTS. as like the code below.

```
AE1 by t1ae1 * (L1)
 t1ae2 t1ae3  t1ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE2 by t2ae1 * (L1)
 t2ae2 t2ae3  t2ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE3 by t3ae1 * (L1)
 t3ae2 t3ae3  t3ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE4 by t4ae1 * (L1)
 t4ae2 t4ae3  t4ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE5 by t5ae1 * (L1)
 t5ae2 t5ae3  t5ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE6 by t6ae1 * (L1)
   t6ae2 t6ae3  t6ae5 (L2-L4);
 AE9 by t9ae1 * (L1)
   t9ae2 t9ae3  t9ae5 (L2-L4);
!2)Item intercepts (tau) all freely estimated except marker indicator, not labeled
 [t1ae1-t9ae1];
 [t1ae2-t9ae2];
 [t1ae3-t9ae3];
 [t1ae5-t9ae5];

 ! 3)item variances all freely estimated, not labeled
 t1ae1-t9ae1;
 t1ae2-t9ae2;
 t1ae3-t9ae3;
 t1ae5-t9ae5;
 ! 4)All Factor variance freely estimated
 AE1-AE9;
 ! 5)All Factor mean freely estimated
 [AE1-AE9];


 ! 7)auto-correlated errors (item-specific)
 t1ae1 with t2ae1 t3ae1 t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
 t2ae1 with t3ae1 t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
 t3ae1 with t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
 t4ae1 with t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
 t5ae1 with t6ae1 t9ae1;
 t6ae1 with t9ae1;

 t1ae2 with t2ae2 t3ae2 t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
 t2ae2 with t3ae2 t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
 t3ae2 with t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
 t4ae2 with t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
 t5ae2 with t6ae2 t9ae2;
 t6ae2 with t9ae2;


 t1ae3 with t2ae3 t3ae3 t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
 t2ae3 with t3ae3 t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
 t3ae3 with t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
 t4ae3 with t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
 t5ae3 with t6ae3 t9ae3;
 t6ae3 with t9ae3;

 t1ae5 with t2ae5 t3ae5 t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
 t2ae5 with t3ae5 t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
 t3ae5 with t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
 t4ae5 with t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
 t5ae5 with t6ae5 t9ae5;
 t6ae5 with t9ae5;


 model constraint:
  L1 = 4 - L2 - L3 - L4;
  !I1 = 0 - I2 - I3 - I4 -I5 - I6 - I7;
```

What puzzles me is that for configural invariance, loadings of different time points (AE1-AE9) are free to have their own loadings. However, if I put the same labels on them, I will be restricting them to be equal across time points. It would be very helpful if someone can tell me how to interpret the code, or, how it should be coded. Thank everybody for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it alright to place equality constraints on the items loadings for assessing configural invariance using effect coding approach?

Yes, invariance/equality of measurement parameters can be tested regardless of the identification method.

https://doi.org/10.5964/meth.10177

> What puzzles me is that for configural invariance, loadings of different time points (AE1-AE9) are free to have their own loadings. However, if I put the same labels on them, I will be restricting them to be equal across time points.

Correct, so the syntax you posted is for metric invariance.  For a configural model, you need to use different labels for loadings across occasions:

```
AE1 by t1ae1 * (t1L1)
 t1ae2 t1ae3  t1ae5 (t1L2-t1L4);
AE2 by t2ae1 * (t2L1)
 t2ae2 t2ae3  t2ae5 (t2L2-t2L4);
```

And apply the effects-coding constraint to each factor's loadings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not been able to find examples of longitudinal invariance testing with effects coding for quite a while so I am really fascinated to get a reply so soon! Thank you again!!

Comment: I just edited my answer so "yes" was more explicit.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I definitely think your answer is useful for lots. I got access to your article at last and will be reading it soon! However, Mplus is giving me error messages for model constraints now. Hope your article will give me good info to figure it out.